# Execute command based on ListView selection with Multiple SelectionMode

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

How to handle command execution using Multiple SelectionMode for Listview?
ListView ItemsSource is bind to a ObservableCollection (EF table) and I've set a limit of selections to 2:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeViewM.MainActivity}"   
                       SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                       IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                       BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                       Background="{x:Null}"
                       VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                       VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"                            
                       VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                       VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item" 
                       VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">

<I:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <limit:LimitSelectionBehavior Limit="2"/>
</I:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I would like to execute command (RelayCommand) based on count of items that are selected. Something like:

```
    If SelectItems.Count = 1 Then
        'Get first item selected
        'Save to the database to table 1
        'Start Timer_01
    ElseIf SelectItems.Count = 2 Then
        'Get last selected item
        'Save to the database to table 2
        'Start Timer_02
    End If
```

How can I handle multiple selections here?
Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the selection changed event of list view and iterate through the list to find out which items are selected. Check the sample code below!

```
public void Selection_Changed(object sender, EventArguments arg)
{
  List<DataClass> selectedItems = new List<DataClass>();

  foreach(DataClass item in LISTVIEWNAME.SelectedItems)
  {
    selectedItems.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Now the **selectedItems** will have the list of selected list items in the list view. Hope you got it!

Comment: Thank you! And how I should do this in MVVM?

Comment: Yes. You can bind the SelectionChanged event of listview to a command in the view model if you are using MVVM architecture.

Comment: If you got the point please mark my answer as correct answer, so that it will help others who have the same issue.